# How to display multiple values of the same attribute when hovering on tooltip with highcharts/highmaps

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, tooltip

I'm using a highmaps worldmap, and when I hover on a country I want the tooltip to list out all of the food chains that are from that specific country. However I'm only managing to get the tooltip to list out the first result. The number of results for each country vary.

For example, I want the tooltip to list out the following food chains when hovering on the US:

1: {companyName: “Burger King“, hc-key: "us"}

2: {companyName: “McDonalds”, hc-key: "us"}

3: {companyName: “Kentucky Fried Chicken”, hc-key: "us"}

4: {companyName: “Quiznos”, hc-key: "us"}

5: {companyName: “Subway”, hc-key: "us"}

6: {companyName: “In and Out“, hc-key: "us"}

7: {companyName: “Taco Bell“, hc-key: "us"}

8: {companyName: “Popeyes”, hc-key: "us"}

9: {companyName: “Jack in the Box”, hc-key: "us"}

10: {companyName: “Italia Pizza”, hc-key: "it"}

10: {companyName: “Italia Pasta”, hc-key: "it"}

My current code outputs the first result, I just don't know enough to edit the tooltip formatter to account for the rest of the results. Thank you.

```
mapdata(Highcharts){
this.companyData
        .getcompanyCountries(this.selectedIndustry)
        .subscribe(
            (data: any[]) => {
                this.companies = data.map(function(el){
                    return {companyName: el.name, 'hc-key':el.country_code}
                })
                console.log(this.companies)
                // Create the chart
                Highcharts.mapChart('container-map', {
                    chart: {
                        map: worldMap,
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    mapNavigation: {
                        enabled: false,
                        buttonOptions: {
                        alignTo: 'spacingBox'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        color: '#ffff00',
                        nullborderColor: '#d3d3d3',
                        type: 'map',
                        name: 'Food Chains',
                        tooltip: {
                           pointFormat: '{point.name}:<br><b>{point.companyName}',
                        },
                        states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#ffff00'
                        }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        format: ''
                        },
                        nullColor: 'white',
                        allAreas: true,
                        joinBy: 'hc-key',
                        data: this.companies,
                    }]


            })
            }

        )}
```

EDITED:

```
mapdata(Highcharts){
this.companyData
        .getcompanyCountries(this.selectedIndustry)
        .subscribe(
            (data: any[]) => {
                this.companies = data.map(function(code){
                    return {companyName: code.name, code: code.country_code}
                })
                console.log(this.companies)
                // Create the chart
                Highcharts.mapChart('container-map', {
                    chart: {
                        map: worldMap,
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                      },
                    mapNavigation: {
                        enabled: false,
                        buttonOptions: {
                        alignTo: 'spacingBox'
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        map: {
                          allAreas: true,
                          joinBy: ['hc-key','code'],
                          dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#FFFFFF',
                            style: {
                              fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                            // Only show dataLabels for areas with high label rank
                            format: null,
                            formatter: function() {
                              if (this.point.properties && this.point.properties.labelrank.toString() < 5) {
                                return this.point.properties['hc-key'];
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '',
                            pointFormatter: function() {
                              var string = '<b>' + this.name + ':<br>';
                              data.forEach(function(companyName) {
                                string += companyName.name + '<br>'
                              });
                              return string;
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },

                    series: [{

                        color: '#ffff00',
                        nullborderColor: '#d3d3d3',
                        type: 'map',
                        name: 'Food Chains',
                        states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#ffff00'
                        }
                        },
                        dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        format: ''
                        },
                        nullColor: 'white',
                        data: this.companies,
                    }]


            })
            }

        )}
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to rework your data model to concat all of the company names for the same country before you pass them to Highcharts

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, good idea might be to use pointFormatter instead of pointFormat, which will help you to easy loop over your companyNames array. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gekrzdto/

Comment: If my solution will meet your requirements I will post it as a final answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Grzegorz, I followed your jsfiddle and was able to list out all of the food chains, however all of the foodchains hover over each country matched (not just their respective countries). Is there a small tweak I can do to fix this problem? I included my edited code that follows yours above. Thanks again.

Comment: Please find my updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gekrzdto/1/

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Grzegorz! You can post is as the final answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use tooltip **pointFormatter** or **pointFormat** options for adding custom information in Highcharts tooltip. You can find more information about this two parameters in Highcharts API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var string = '<b>' + this.name + ':<br>';
      this.companyNames.forEach(function(name) {
        string += name + '<br>'
      });
      return string;
    }
  }
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gekrzdto/1/